# add fields in admin.py from a ManyToMany

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, admin

I would like to display for each question page that corresponds to it i have 4 items in my class page ( "visit 1 visit 2 visit 3 visit 4")

For now I seem to get all the pages at once ... I want if for example the question "How old are you?" is defined with the visit 1 this turn around in the admin panel "Visite 1" only

> My models.py :

```
class Page(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Question(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    page = models.ManyToManyField(Page)

    def __str__(self):
            return self.label

class Reply(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    creationDate = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 20, 15, 4, 21, 467165))

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.answer)
```

> My admin.py :

```
class ReplyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__str__", "user", "question", "creationDate", "get_pages",]

    def get_pages(self, objects):
        return "\n".join([page.title for page in Page.objects.all()])

    class Meta:
        model = Reply   
admin.site.register(Reply, ReplyAdmin)
```

**What is the loop that I must face to get the right line for each associated pages**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class ReplyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ["__str__", "user", "question", "creationDate", "get_pages",]

    def get_pages(self, obj):
        return "\n".join([page.title for page in obj.question.page.all()])

    class Meta:
        model = Reply   
admin.site.register(Reply, ReplyAdmin)
```